# can you access and execute start, drag, stop functions of draggable in other areas of code?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

If i have a object:

```
<div id="tar"></div>
```

and want to apply draggable:

```
$("div#tar").draggable({
    start: function(){...},
    drag:  function(){...},
    stop:  function(){...}
});
```

and want to call those functions for some reason outside of the function, i naturally say:  Well, move the anon out, and give it a name like:

```
function abc(){...}
$("div#tar").draggable({start:abc});
```

but what if there  is another way?

I am curious if i can find and call/execute the function 'start' from another function or reference.

So if i was somewhere and wanted to call it do something like:

```
$("div#tar").draggable["start"]();
```

or something of that nature.

Does anyone know how i would go about doing the latter of the 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some other ways:

You can call your callback functions defined at widget creation time like this:

```
$("div#tar").draggable("option", "start").call();
```

Or bind your callbacks using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), and then trigger the associated events using [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

```
$("div#tar").draggable().on('dragstart', function() {...})
$("div#tar").trigger('dragstart');
```

Open your js console view (F12) and have a look in this <kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MqmK5/1/)</kbd>

Comment: The first answer you provided is the exact answer i was thinking.  Granted, i was using "stop" in my example, but i get what you are saying.   Thank you! :)